# How to count if all documents in a group have a value set to 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a document review tool, one can create "batches" of documents. A batch is a group of related documents, identified by GroupID.

These groups of documents are presented to reviewers, who update a field called Testcompleted. This field has 3 possible states: 1, 0 or null. The number of documents in a group varies.

In the example below I have 3 groups ("batches") of documents. The first batch (batch_0001), for instance, has 2 documents (58 and 59).

```
#Document

ArtifactID    Testcompleted    GroupID
--------------------------------------
58            1                4
59            1                4
60            null             6
61            1                6
62            null             7
63            null             7
64            null             7

#DocumentBatch

BatchArtifactID    DocumentArtifactID
-------------------------------------
66                 58
66                 59
67                 60
67                 61
68                 62
68                 63
68                 64


#Batch

ArtifactID    Name
------------------------
66            batch_0001
67            batch_0002
68            batch_0003
```

I need to know when a batch is completed -- that is: when all documents in that batch have the Testcompleted field set to 1. In the example, this is the case for batch_0001.

The output I am looking for is:

```
batch           documents       reviewed     completed
------------------------------------------------------
batch_0001      2               2            yes
batch_0002      2               1            no
batch_0003      3               0            no
```

I started by joining the tables:

```
select
    *
from
    #Document d

    left join #DocumentBatch db
    on db.DocumentArtifactID = b.ArtifactID

    left join #Batch b
    on db.BatchArtifactID = b.ArtifactID
where
    d.Testcompleted = 1
;
```

This obviously does not return the result I need, but I am stuck. Some help on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, when the SUM(TestCompleted) of a set equals the COUNT of the same set?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek Correct :)

Comment: Why are you allowing nulls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    b.name, 
    count(db.DocumentArtifactID) as documents,
    -- count only completed
    count(case when d.Testcompleted = 1 then d.ArtifactID end) as reviewed,
    -- if the minimum = 1 there's no 0 or NULL
    case when min(cast(Testcompleted as tinyint)) = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end as completed
from
    #Batch b

    left join #DocumentBatch db
    on db.BatchArtifactID = b.ArtifactID

    left join #Document d
    on db.DocumentArtifactID = d.ArtifactID
group by b.name;
```

If there are no missing rows you can switch to Inner Joins...

Comment: I get an error: operand data type bit is invalid for min operator?

Comment: @Pr0no: You didn't tell it's a bit, ok, it's the natural choice for 0/1. You must CAST it, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
select b.name
     , count(*) as documents
     , sum(d.Testcompleted) as reviewed
     , (case when count(*) = sum(d.Testcompleted) then 'yes' else 'no' end) as completed
from [#Document] d
join [#DocumentBatch] db on db.DocumentArtifactID = d.ArtifactID
join [#Batch] b on db.BatchArtifactID = b.ArtifactID
group by b.name
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45187/3)

- `count(*)` includes into calculation all values;
- `sum(d.Testcompleted)` count only cases where `Testcompleted` is `1`;

Comment: I don't think (not sure) you want to count the zeros.

Comment: What if `TestCompleted` is zero? You should use `SUM(d.Testcompleted)` instead.

Comment: Indeed -- a document is only considered reviewed if the value for Testcompleted = 1. In this case, the 0 is also counted, making for a wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is aggregation,so you need a `group by`.  Something like this:

```
select b.name as batchname, count(d.ARtifactID) as numdocuments,
       sum(case when d.testCompleted = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as NumCompleted,
       (case when sum(case when d.testCompleted = 1 then 0 else 1 end) > 0
             then 'No'
             else 'Yes'
        end) as AllCompleted
from #Batch b left join
     #DocumentBatch db     
     on db.BatchArtifactID = b.ArtifactID
     #Document d left join
     on db.DocumentArtifactID = b.ArtifactID left join
group by b.name;
```

I don't think outer joins are needed.  You should be able to use `inner join`, unless there are batches with no documents.  If you do use outer joins, starting with `#Batch` makes more sense than `#Document`, because you are aggregating at the batch level.